# jQuery Vimeo Auto Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo

I have an image being displayed and a vimeo player(s) below the image. By default the vimeo player is hidden (not display: none; nor visibility: hidden). When the user clicks on the image the vimeo player takes the place of the image and is now visible. Now my question is how can I make the video player auto play after it becomes visible.

My jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".image-caption p a").click(function () {

    $('.image-block').css('display','none');
    $('.sqs-video-wrapper').css('position', 'relative');
    $('.sqs-video-wrapper').css('top', '0');

  });

});
```

Works perfect! Just need the vimeo player to auto play. It is wrapped in an iFrame by default of course.

Here's a quick demo of what I would like:

http://thisisdk.com/work/scrapbook

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the autoplay parameter to true (or 1) in the embed code, when the video is displayed, it should play automatically.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pgPp/)

Comment: That is true but it will auto play regardless if the user clicks on "click me"

Comment: hmmm must be browser specific then. In FF Mac, the video doesn't play.

Comment: same in Safari and Chrome, video doesn't play until it becomes visible.
Another solution would be to inject the HTML on the click.

Comment: Hmmm well since its browser...is there any browser hacks out there. Cause this feature has to go as planned :(

Comment: How bout this: http://jsfiddle.net/3pgPp/1/

Comment: I've used the HTML injection to do this many times. Works everywhere.